# How do I change the color of points on my graph that are attached to a factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following function that I am using to try and create a graph that shows the different sexes as well as the difference in length and weight of fish.

```
ggplot(fish1,aes(x=Weight...,y=Fork.Length...,col = Sex))+geom_point()
```

However, I have been told that using red and green in a plot is not advisable due to colorblind people.  How can I change what colors R assigns to each of my factors.  Since this is an scatter-plot I cannot just do a `col = c("red","yellow" "blue")` as that list would have to be 132 factors long.

Here is my list of Sex factors:

```
# [1]   M M M M M M M U U M F F F M F M F F M
# [20]  F M M M M F F F M M M M M M F M M M M
# [39]  M M F F M M F M M M M M F M F F F M F
# [58]  F F F F F F M F M F U F M U F M M F F
# [77]  M F U M M M M M U M F U F F F U M F M
# [96]  F F U U F F M F M M F F M F F F M F M
# [115] F M F M M M F M F F F F F F M F M F
```

Comment: `+ scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","yellow","blue"))` or, if you want to ensure a specific color is mapped to a specific factor level, regardless of factor ordering, then use a named vector of colors: `+ scale_colour_manual(values=c("M"="red","F"="yellow","U"="blue"))`

Comment: Thank you!  Would you mind explaining how those two functions change what I just did?

Comment: When you include `aes(colour=sex)` in a plot, ggplot2 uses a default color palette to set the color for each level of `sex`. Likewise, ggplot2 has defaults for axis ranges, point marker shapes, etc. `scale` functions (e.g., `scale_colour_manual`, `scale_x_discrete`, `scale_colour_hue`, `scale_shape_continuous`, etc.) are how you change those default values to whatever colours, point marker shapes, axis ranges, etc. that you want.